# Symfony3 ConstraintViolation error when select on extra option of an EntityType

Tags: symfony, validation

I build a form contain a field of an entity type:

```
/**
 * Show account  register form.
 *
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder Builder to modify
 */
protected function showAccountRegisterForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder)
{
    $builder
        ->add('bank',
            EntityType::class,
            [
                'class' => 'AdminBundle:Bank',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'required' => false,
                'translation_domain' => 'form',
                'placeholder' => 'Choose a bank',
            ]
        )
    ;
}
```

and I add one more option for user to select which call "Other" by using finishView function:

```
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    //new option
    $other = new ChoiceView(array(), 'other', $this->translator->trans('bank.option.other'));
    //adding the new option
    $view->children['bank']->vars['choices'][] = $other;
}
```

everything works fine and it render 'other' option for me, but when I select the option 'other' and submit, I got a form error on that entity.
Anyone know how to solve this problem? thank you

I think the problem here it's because the value is 'other'
 which is a string and our filed is an EntityType, that why it's cause ConstraintViolation error. I searching on this for a few days already but could find the right answer. 
[image]

Comment: The value "other does not exist on your entity validation.
Replaces 'other' with '' and manages it in the controller at the time of submission of form.
the entity type Is not made to handle the special cases, just accepted the null case in function finishview or use ChoiceType for manuel configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You are using entity type and you are trying to submit entity that does not exists. You need to have actual record of the choice in the database if you want to use entity type.

Comment: So if I use EntityType, the selection that render have to have the same record value in database? If it is so, is there's any other type that I can use instead of EntityType? Thanks

Comment: You can use the choice type docs here http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally ended up by remove 'bank' from form builder to void form validation and validate by myself in controller, then in controller pass banks to template and loop though it to create selection, and finally get bank from request instead.

To help somebody to save their time on the case that you need to use an **extra field with Symfony form**. Here the point, I did test on EntityType and ChoiceType, both of them require the data that you send exists when the form was rendered, if the data that you send not exist it will cause form **ConstraintViolation error**. So in the case that the data that you send is a new data(option) add by js it will error. Another case similar to this, if you use EntityType and use query_builder(same as use ChoiceType and get your choice from a function), the new data(option) that you add by js most be able to get by the query that you write. 
Ex: your query_builder will get only the bank that has status true, but the new bank that you just add status was false, this also cause error.

Hope this would help :)